# Can we refocus certain badges?

Tags: feature-request

Rather than have badges that can't be won ever again like Precognition, why not make them more general, like first to do X Y or Z?  The site is apparently still in beta, so there should be a lot of opportunities to be the first to help out with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. The badges are general for all SO websites. See some details about it here: [Remove impossible badges from per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121922/224252). There is one badge that can't be earned even on stackoverflow.com